# How to avoid global variables in command function call

Tags: python, tkinter, global

I'm still working on a code that moves around two planets and shows the gravitational force between them. I tried to make it easier to use by just showing two buttons that allow to select the planet you want to move. Then you can click in the canvas and the selected planet will move where you've clicked.

The programm works, but I'd like to know if there is a better way to write it then using the `chngB` and `chngO` functions with global statements.
I still can't believe that in Python you are forced to use a function without parameters when assigning it to the `command` parameter of a button.

Basically I'd like to know if it's just possible to write something like `command = (a=1)`
(I know that this doesn't work, but you get the idea.)
Also, there probably just is another way of doing it than having to use a variable to know which planet is selected (which button has been pressed last).

I use Python 3.

```
from tkinter import *
import math

x, y = 135, 135
a = 0

def gravitation (obj1,obj2):#showing gravitational force between planets 
    a, b, c, d = can.coords (obj1)
    e, f, g, h = can.coords (obj2)
    dist = math.sqrt ((((a+c)/2)-((e+g)/2))**2+(((b+d)/2)-((f+h)/2))**2)
    if dist != 0:
        grav = 6.67384/dist
    else:
        grav = "Infinite"
    str(grav)
    return grav

def chngB ():#Telling Blue planet is selected
    global a
    a = 1

def chngO ():#Telling Orange planet is selected
    global a
    a = 0

def updt ():#Updating gravitation label
    lbl.configure (text = gravitation(oval1, oval2)) 


def moveBlue (event):#Placing blue planet where mouse click on canv
    coo = [event.x-15, event.y-15, event.x+15, event.y+15]
    can.coords(oval1, *coo)
    updt()

def moveOrange (event):#Placing orange planet where mouse click on canv
    coo = [event.x-15, event.y-15, event.x+15, event.y+15]
    can.coords(oval2, *coo)
    updt()

def choice (event):#Function binded to can, move the selected planet (blue = 1, prange = 0)
    if a == 0:
        moveOrange(event)
    else :
        moveBlue(event)

##########MAIN############

wind = Tk() # Window and canvas
wind.title ("Move Da Ball")
can = Canvas (wind, width = 300, height = 300, bg = "light blue")
can.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky =W, padx = 5, pady = 5, rowspan =3)
can.bind ("<Button-1>", choice)
Button(wind, text = 'Quit', command=wind.destroy).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky =W, padx = 5, pady = 5)

oval1 = can.create_oval(x,y,x+30,y+30,width=2,fill='blue') #Planet 1 moving etc
buttonBlue = Button(wind, text = 'Blue Planet', command = chngB)
buttonBlue.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky =W, padx = 5, pady = 5)

oval2 = can.create_oval(x+50,y+50,x+80,y+80,width=2,fill='orange') #Planet 2 moving etc
buttonOrange = Button(wind, text = 'Orange Planet', command = chngO)
buttonOrange.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky =W, padx = 5, pady = 5)

lbl = Label(wind, bg = 'white')#label
lbl.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky =W, padx = 5, pady = 5, columnspan = 3)
gravitation (oval1, oval2)

wind.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, if you want a button to toggle a variable between one of N values, you would use a set of radiobuttons. When you use a radiobutton you can associate it with a variable so that whenever you click the button, the variable is automatically selected.

For example:

```
planet = IntVar()
planet.set(0)

buttonBlue = Radiobutton(wind, text="Blue Planet", variable=planet, value=1)
buttonOrange = Radiobutton(wind, text="Orange Planet", variable=planet, value=0)
...
def choice (event):#Function binded to can, move the selected planet (blue = 1, prange = 0)
    if planet.get() == 0:
        moveOrange(event)
    else :
        moveBlue(event)
```

If you really want to use a regular button, you can do that with a single callback rather than two, and then use `lambda` or `functools.partial` to pass in the new value.

For example:

```
buttonBlue = Button(wind, text = 'Blue Planet', command = lambda: change(1))
buttonOrange = Button(wind, text = 'Blue Planet', command = lambda: change(0))
def change(newValue):
    global a
    a = newValue
```

Comment: Hi. I don't know what an IntVar is, but I'll find out. Otherwise, I get the concept of what you have written, and that was actually exactly the kind of answer I was waiting for, as I wanted _to know if there is a better way to write it then using the chngB and chngO functions with global statements._

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot have a lambda expression with a statement (assignment) in it.
But you can easily have just one setter function which returns a closure that you can pass to your `Button` constructor.  Here's an example of creating and using closures:

```
a = 0

def set_a (v):
    def closure ():
        global a
        a = v
    return closure

command = set_a(42)
command()
print a    # prints 42

command = set_a(17)
command()
print a    # prints 17
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works fine but I'm not sure if I get it. Writing 'command = closure(1)' doesn't work because you assign the resulting value to 'command', and you're not calling the function. But when you write 'command = set_a(42)' aren't you also assigning a value to 'command'? Of course you're not, since it works, but I don't get why.

Comment: The `closure` is something internal in the setter; you don't call that directly.  The result of, say, `set_a(42)` is a **function** that, when called without arguments, will set `a` to 42.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. So basically we could say that when you assign a function to a command, the assigned result will only be one 'level' deeper. In this case, it's the call of closure and not it's returned value.